# Google Earth Engine: running NDVI analysis by month

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series

How would I go about making my analysis values per month rather than per year

```
 Create date filter and vector of years for analysis
       var date_filter = ee.Filter.date('2010-06-22', '2022-06-22');
       var year = ee.List.sequence(2010,2022);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not describing what type of monthly analysis you want to do. The below generates an image collection with monthly means for a date range. Maybe it at least can give you an idea on how to go about.

```
var aoi = Map.getBounds(true)
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2022-07-01')

var ndviCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
      .rename('ndvi')
      .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
      .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
  })

var numberOfMonths = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months')
var monthOffsets = ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfMonths.subtract(1))
var monthlyNdviCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  monthOffsets.map(function (monthOffset) {
    var dateRange = startDate
      .advance(ee.Number(monthOffset), 'months')
      .getRange('month')
    return ndviCollection
      .filterDate(dateRange)
      .median()
      .set('system:time_start', dateRange.start().millis())
      .set('system:time_end', dateRange.end().millis())
  })
)

Map.addLayer(monthlyNdviCollection)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ce3ee6c937f87b19a9acf87d580b15f2

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to compute and download different spectral indices (including NDVI) using Sentinel-2 images. The script allows to obtain monthly composites using the `forEach` loop:

```
// Processing steps:
// 0) Define input parameters.
// 1) Search and filtering imagery by date, in the study area, and clouds <75%.
// 2) Mask images to create 'crear sky' composites using the SCL product.
// 3) Compute some vegetation indices: NDVI, EVI, SAVI, OSAVI, NDMI, NDWI, MSI, MSI2.
// 4) Feature extraction (central position features) - compute monthly composites of 'mean' from the time serie.
// 5) Download data - Google Drive.

// Define extension of the study area.
//var extent = ... your feature collection...

// Define time intervals (periods) to compute statistics.
var periods = [['2018-09-01', '2018-09-30'],
               ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-31'],
               ['2018-11-01', '2018-11-30'],
               ['2018-12-01', '2018-12-31'],
               ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'],
               ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'],
               ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-31'],
               ['2019-04-01', '2019-04-30'],
               ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-31'],
               ['2019-06-01', '2019-06-30'],
               ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'],
               ['2019-08-01', '2019-08-31']];

var extent = ee.FeatureCollection('feature_collection');

// Run process for all periods.
periods.forEach(exportPeriod);

function exportPeriod(period) {
  
  // Import and filter Sentinel-2 data.
  var s2RawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate(period[0], period[1])
    .filterBounds(extent);
  
  // Generate 'clear_sky' Sentinel-2 images using SCL.
  var s2ClearSky = function(image) {
    var scl = image.select('SCL');
    var clearSkyPixels = scl.eq(4).or(scl.eq(5)).or(scl.eq(6)).or(scl.eq(11));
    return image.updateMask(clearSkyPixels);
  };
  var s2Data = s2RawData.map(s2ClearSky);
  
  // Compute spectral indices.
  var addSpectralIndices = function(image){
  // Sentinel-2 bands
  var s2Bands = 
  {'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000),
   'GREEN': image.select('B3').divide(10000),
   'RED': image.select('B4').divide(10000),
   'NIR': image.select('B8').divide(10000),
   'SWIR1': image.select('B11').divide(10000),
   'SWIR2': image.select('B12').divide(10000)};
  // Vegetation indices
  var ndvi = image.expression('((NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED))', s2Bands).rename('NDVI');
  var evi = image.expression('2.5*((NIR-RED)/(1+NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE))', s2Bands).rename('EVI');
  var savi = image.expression('(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.5)*(1+0.5)', s2Bands).rename('SAVI');
  var osavi = image.expression('(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.16)*(1+0.16)', s2Bands).rename('OSAVI');
  // Water and moisture indices
  var ndmi = image.expression('((NIR-SWIR1)/(NIR+SWIR1))', s2Bands).rename('NDMI');
  var ndwi = image.expression('((NIR-SWIR2)/(NIR+SWIR2))', s2Bands).rename('NDWI');
  var msi = image.expression('(SWIR1/NIR)', s2Bands).rename('MSI');
  var msi2 = image.expression('SWIR2/NIR', s2Bands).rename('MSI2');
  // Add spectral indices
  var newBands = ee.Image([ndvi, evi, savi, osavi, ndmi, ndwi, msi, msi2]);
  return image.addBands(newBands);
  };
  var s2DataSi = s2Data.map(addSpectralIndices);
  print(s2DataSi);

  // Extract period features from the spectral indices time series.
  var ndvi = s2DataSi.select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "NDVI");
  //print(ndvi);
  var evi = s2DataSi.select('EVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "EVI");
  //print(evi);
  var savi = s2DataSi.select('SAVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "SAVI");
  //print(savi);
  var osavi = s2DataSi.select('OSAVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "OSAVI");
  //print(savi);
  var ndmi = s2DataSi.select('NDMI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "NDMI");
  //print(ndmi);
  var ndwi = s2DataSi.select('NDWI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "NDWI");
  //print(ndwi);
  var msi = s2DataSi.select('MSI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "MSI");
  //print(msi);
  var msi2 = s2DataSi.select('MSI2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
           .set("system:id", "MSI2");
  //print(msi2);

  // Merge extracted features into a ee.FeatureCollection
  var s2ExtFeatures = ee.ImageCollection([ndvi, evi, savi, osavi, ndmi, ndwi, msi, msi2]);
  print(s2ExtFeatures);
  
  // Export extracted features.
  var folder = period[0] + '_' + period[1];
  var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
  batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s2ExtFeatures, folder, 
                {name: '{system:id}' + '_name_' + folder,
                 scale: 10, 
                 region: extent, 
                 type: 'float'});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
var image  =  ee.ImageCollection("COLLECTION")
var_filtered_image  =  image.filter(ee.Filter.ed('cadance', 'monthly')) // I think this line should handle the monthly part
  .filterDate('2010-06-22', '2022-06-22').toList(); // This handles the year
```

I have adopted this from the code on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7lCNNJOfZY&ab_channel=OpenSourceRemoteSensing%26GIS